# What is this array initializer in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a multidimensional array,

```
double anarray[2][2] = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };
```

I have a function

```
void afunction(double anarray[2][2], int i, int j)
{
   double (*a) [2] = anarray[i];// 1
   double *a[2] = {anarray[i]}; // 2
}
```

What does 1 do? What are the differences between **1** and **2** ?

Comment: What makes you say they are the same? They don't have the same type, for starters.

Comment: I've changed the question, I thought it was the same, I don't know what **1** does then...

Comment: [This might be helpful reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) - it's about dynamic allocation but it also explains the concept of arrays and array decay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many differences. First of all, the types (and note that I'm renaming the variables because you gave them the same name):

```
double (* p)[2];
double * q[2];
```

C's declarations with nested parentheses are notoriously confusing, but the rules are generally simple:

- The parentheses take precedence (that's what they are for)
- In absence of them, things to the right take precedence over things to the left
- When dealing with several modifiers next to each other (e.g., `int p[3][4];`), the closest ones to the variable name take precedence

(They are technically operators and operands, but I'm not calling them that because it's easy to confuse them with actual operators that show up in expressions.)

So let's parse them:

- `p` is a pointer (the first thing that applies is the `*` that is enclosed within it in the parentheses) to a two-element array of doubles.
- `q` is a two-element array (the `[2]` on the right takes precedence over the `*` on the left) of pointers to double.

And is there anything else of those types? Well, yes.

```
void function (double array[2][2], int i, int j) { /* ... */ }
```

As you probably know, when used in an expression, arrays decay to pointers. If `x` is declared `int x[20];`, when used in an expression it decays to an `int *`. And what about multidimensional arrays? Well, they decay too, but only one layer, of course: a pointer to a pointer isn't the same as a pointer to an array. So something like `int y[3][4]`, which is a three-element array of four-element arrays of integers, will decay to a pointer to the same element type: a pointer to four-element arrays of integers. In other words, `int (*) [4]`. (The variable name would go inside the parentheses, after the `*`. You can use the rules above to figure out the type!)

So, that function argument would decay to `double (*) [2]` when used — the same type as `p`! And thus, assigning them directly would be perfectly legal:

```
double (* p)[2] = array;
```

But since you took an index to the array in your example, you created something invalid. Remember that `foo[bar]` is equivalent to `*(foo + bar)` in C. Adding an offset to a pointer doesn't change its type, so `array + i` would still have the same type — but when you dereference it by doing `array[i]` (or equivalently, `*(array + i)`), you're removing one layer of indirection and turning the value into a `double [2]`, which immediately decays to `double *`. That pointer type is incompatible with `p`'s, and thus you (should) get an error, or at least a warning that you should really pay attention to.

On the other hand, you can make `p` point to an element in the (outer) array other than the first:

```
double (* p)[2] = array + 1;
```

(Some people prefer doing `&array[1]` instead of `array + 1`. They are equivalent; choose whichever form you want.)

Now for the other variable. That's a two-element array of pointers. So when you do this:

```
double * q[2] = {array[i]};
```

...you're really doing this, since missing entries are zero-initialized:

```
double * q[2] = {array[i], NULL};
```

However, this one is perfectly legal and it works, although probably not as you intended. As I said before, `array[i]` is of type `double *` — and since this is an array of `double *` elements, the assignment works without errors. So now you have `q` as a two-element array, where the first element points into the `i`'th row of `array` and the second element is a null pointer. It's valid, but almost certainly not what you intended — something like `q[1][0]` would be undefined behavior right away, since `q[1]` is a null pointer and you'd be dereferencing it by doing `[0]` on it.

Comment: Can I give you a million likes !? Amazing explanation, a big round of applause for you !

Answer (score 1):

1) is an array pointer to an array of type `double[2]`. You cannot have it point at `anarray[i]` since that expression decays into a `double*`, which is a different pointer type. It has to be written `double (*a) [2] = &anarray[i];// 1`, where & prevents "array decay".

2) creates an array of 2 `double*`, the first one pointing at the first item of `anarray[i]` and the second one implicitly set to point at NULL, since you left it out of the initializer list.

Comment: Because you need braces to initialize an array. `int foo[3] = 8;` doesn't work either. `int foo[3] = {8};` _does_, because missing values are filled with zeros.